# My PATH variable seems to be set OK, but does not work

Tags: paths

I installed some programm (xlsx2csv) using pip3. The executable of the software is in `~/.local/bin`.
My `$PATH` is defined in `~/.profile` like this:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

echo $PATH
/home/bruni/bin:/home/bruni/.local/bin:/home/bruni/bin:/home/bruni/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Permissions on the executable seem ok:

```
bruni@bruni-Inspiron-5547:~/.local/bin$ ls -l
total 44
-rwxrwxr-x 1 bruni bruni 42501 Jul  2 12:39 xlsx2csv

bruni@bruni-Inspiron-5547:~/.local/bin$ type -a xlsx2csv 
xlsx2csv is /home/bruni/.local/bin/xlsx2csv
xlsx2csv is /home/bruni/.local/bin/xlsx2csv
```

Nonetheless, I cannot invoke the installed software without specifying the exact path.

```
:~$ xlsx2csv
-bash: /usr/bin/xlsx2csv: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo $PATH` and `type -a xlsx2csv`?

Comment: For some reason you have `/home/bruni/bin:/home/bruni/.local/bin:` on your PATH twice, but I doubt that would break it. Still would be worth removing the duplicate IMHO. And what exactly is the error message when you try to run the command `xlsx2csv`? You could also run `hash -r` to clear some command path caches and try again afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have the executable `xlsx2csv` in your `~/.local/bin` folder, which is added to the `$PATH` variable correctly (even twice, which should be fixed, but is not critical).

It is correctly recognized as executable there, as we can see from the output of `type -a xlsx2csv`, which lists us all types/locations of the given command (could be e.g. shell built-in/function/alias or executable file - type `help type` for more info).

However, Bash believes it can be found as `/usr/bin/xlsx2csv`, as you see in the error when trying to invoke it.

This is a result of Bash (and other shells) using an internal hash table to speed up command look-ups. Probably the wrong entry is there because you had such an executable in that location earlier and ran it, but then it got moved or uninstalled and reinstalled int he other location.

Normally Bash resets its hash table when there are events that obviously invalidate it, like when you change the `$PATH` variable. It did obviously not recognize your re-installation procedure there though, but we can reset it manually:

```
hash -r
```

This command above resets Bash's command hash table and clears all the cached command location entries, forcing it to do a regular look-up in your `$PATH` the next time you type any command. You can see the current hash table by typing `hash` only. For more information, read its help by typing `help hash`. You can also visit [What is the purpose of the hash command? (Unix & Linux SE)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86017/103151) for more information about Bash's command location hashing.